# Travis CI: Build intermittently fails and log takes forever to load (never loads)

Tags: travis-ci

This is my build.
https://travis-ci.org/gogo/protobuf
It intermittently fails for some of the builds.
I think it is struggling with installing a protocol buffer version using wget, but I can't see the logs, since they take forever to load.
It would be great if travis could tell me that it has failed to load the logs instead of just pretending to load them.  Sorry I don't know if that is really the case, but that is how it feels.
Also I don't understand why this works some of the time and randomly fails.  If the server is overloaded, put me in a queue, please don't fail when there is not something wrong with the code.
Please help I am new to travis, so maybe I am just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other builds with the same use of PROTOBUF_VERSION are successful and show some output from the final step of install-protobuf.sh (`./configure --prefix=/home/travis && make -j2 && make install`).  So similar to you, I suspect that the wget step in install-protobuf.sh is what is failing in the failed builds.

I would suggest editing `install-protobuf.sh` so that you can better see what is going on in the travis-ci logs:

- change set command to: `set -ex`
- remove the `-q` option from your use of wget in:
  `wget -q https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v$PROTOBUF_VERSION/$basename.tar.gz`

Comment: I have made the changes, but before and after the changes it is now passing for some reason.

Comment: I suspect that its something like the following is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163758/travis-build-getting-errored-randomly-due-to-timeout-authentication-failure    It would explain how sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: and with your updated travis.yml, you hopefully will see if that is the case, if a build fails again.

Comment: Seems like its pretty stable now.  Maybe its just, like you said, because I made so many build requests in a short period.